# MIPS Runtime Error “Cannot read directly from text segment”

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips

```
.data
    matrixA: .word 1,2,3
             .word 4,5,6
             .word 7,8,9
    matrixX: .word 1
             .word 2
             .word 3
    matrixB: .word 0
             .word 0
             .word 0
.text
    main: 
         la $s0, matrixA 
         la $s1, matrixX 
         la $s2, matrixB
         
         addi $v1, $zero, 0 
         addi $t2, $zero, 0 
         addi $t3, $zero, 0
for:
beq $t3, 3, IncreaseCoindex
        mul $t6, $t3, 4
        add $t5, $s1, $t6            
        lw  $t4, ($t5)
        mul $t7, $t2, 3               
        add $t0, $t7, $t3          
        mul  $t0, $t0, 4    
         
        add  $t0, $t0, $s0            
        lw   $t1, ($t0)
        mul  $t1, $t1, $t4   
        add  $v1, $v1, $t1
        addi $t3, $t3, 1
IncreaseCoindex: 
       mul $t6, $t2, 4       
       add $t6, $s2, $t6             
       sw  $v1, ($t6)                
           lw $a0, ($t6)
           li $v0, 1
           syscall
           jal printNewLine              
                addi $t2, $t2, 1
                addi $t3, $zero, 0       
                addi $v1, $zero, 0       
                blt $t2, 3, for         
   exit:
      li $v0, 10
      syscall
   printNewLine:
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, printNewLine
      syscall
      jr $ra
```

> Error in line 50: Runtime exception at 0x004000a4: Cannot read directly from text segment!0x00400098
>
> Go: execution terminated with errors.

What should I do.....?

The question is to calculate Ax = b (A: 3x3, x: 3x1)

Comment: You should at the very least have pointed out which instruction the error message refers to. In any case, you don't seem to be exporting your `main` label. That is, before `main:` you should have a line that says `.globl main`

Comment: If you solved your problem then please post the answer here. That would help future readers...